# The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am VERY new to ASP.NET MVC (3) and am having a hard time resolving a build error in Visual Studio:

The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyProjectName.Models
{   
    public class MachineModel
    {
        // name
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nom de la machine")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // IP
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)",
           ErrorMessage = "Donnez une adresse IPv4 valide.")]
        [Display(Name = "Adresse IP de la machine")]
        public string IP { get; set; }
    }

    public class MachineDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MachineModel> Machines{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

The two errors I am getting are:

- The type or namespace name
  'DbContext' could not be found (are
  you missing a using directive or an
  assembly reference?)
- The type or namespace name 'DbSet'
  could not be found (are you
  missing a using directive or an
  assembly reference?)

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add the Entity Framework Code First reference using NuGet? That might be the easiest way to resolve references.

Comment: o.k. - under the Solution Explorer Tree I did a right-click on References -> Add Library Package Reference -> EFCodeFirst -> Install. Is this what you were suggesting? After following these steps I still have the same problem.

Comment: I have meanwhile updated the MVC 3 Tools to the newest version, and created a tutorial project following http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part4-cs. In that project, I don't have this problem, but I can't get DbContext to be accepted in my older project, despite the suggestions made here and by Darin below...

Comment: VS2017, EF6, Close the solution. Reopen solution. It now properly recognizes DbContext.

Comment: Open the Package Manager Console. Select Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console.

In the Package Manager Console, enter the following command:
install-package EntityFramework

Comment: Why is this question closed?  Thank goodness there are some answers here that helped, before an overzealous mod closed it.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I had the same issue. Turns out, you need the EntityFramework.dll reference (and not System.Data.Entity).

I just pulled it from the MvcMusicStore application which you can download from: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

It's also a useful example of how to use entity framework code-first with MVC.

Comment: this was my experience; the EntityFramework.dll for 4.2.0.0 was not present even though the vs2010 Package Manager claimed I had 4.2.0.0 installed.  With my project open in vs2010, running the [install command](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.2.0.0) via Tools, Library Package Manager, Package Manager Console added the reference to **EntityFramework** automatically and my subsequent build succeeded.  thnx @Shahzad!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hope Microsoft would one day make installation of their own software on their windows easier! It is amazing how many places one has to go to to figure what is needed and how they all fit together. NuGet, MS Download site, Message boards, books,....very productive time indeed.

Comment: Your best bet is to use NuGet (package manager) to pull Entity Framework (et al) into your projects.

Comment: some times you need to restart visual studio to make the installation works. this was my case.

Comment: You can use the Nuget Manage Packages for Solutions. Find EntityFramework and click Manage. There will be check boxes to where it is installed next to each project. Make sure you are using the version of EF you need. You can use multiple versions in the same solution, for various reasons.

Comment: Open Package Manager Console and paste in: Install-Package EntityFramework

Comment: I had a similar issue after installing the entity framework from Nuget. Rebuilding the solution seemed to sort this out...

Comment: System.Data.Entity did the trick for me

Answer (score 73):

You need to reference the `System.Data.Entity` assembly in your project, or
install the `EntityFramework` NuGet package, which will setup everything for you.

Comment: Darin, could you explain how one would do this?

Comment: @Chris Dickinson, right click on the `References` item in the project and select `Add Reference...`. Then in the `.NET` tab, select `System.Data.Entity`. And if you want to use NuGet, right click on the `References` item and then select `Add Library Package Reference...` and in the Online tab, search for `EntityFramework`.

Comment: I followed both of your steps, but the problem still persists...

Comment: did u use NuGet to install EntityFramework?It creates a folder "packages" along side your Solution directory. You will find the "EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0" folder inside it.Within "Libs" folder you will find "EntityFramework.dll" .Add reference to it using Browse tab and select the above dll. see my answer below.. i did the same.

Comment: Required assembly reference is EntityFramework.dll, not System.Data.Entity. I had to do the full Entity Framework 4.1 install to get it - NuGet did not pull the appropriate assembly for me.

Comment: I selected `TOOLS > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console` in VS2012 and typed `install-package EntityFramework` at the prompt.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: Only adding the reference to System.Data.Entity still left me with DbContext not being recognized. Also following @PeterGluck his comment worked for me. Small update for VS2017: `>Tools >NuGet Package Manager >Package Manager Console` and type `install-package EntityFramework`.

Answer (score 20):

Just a quick note. It is DbContext, not DBContext. i.e. with a lowercase 'B'. I discovered this because I had the same problem while intelesense was not working until I tried typing the full name space System.Data.Entity... and name and finally it suggested the lowercase 'b' option:-

System.Data.Entity.DbContext

Comment: I've been going through all the references regarding System.Data.Entity only to discover that the problem was the uppercase "B". +1

Comment: Yes this solved it. Provided "Install-Package EntityFramework" step was done. Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem using VS2010. 
I know this isn't really an answer. I just thought it might help someone.
I resolved it by using the fully qualified name for DBContext.

Instead of

```
public class MachineDbContext : DbContext
```

I used

```
public class MachineDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
```

and rebuilt the project. Suddenly VS was happy, and I was even able to remove the fully qualified name, and just use DBContext.

Comment: This worked for me, but it seems very bizarre that I need to fully qualify the DbContext even though the using statement is already in place.  Does anyone have any insight on why this is happening?

Comment: or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext - worked for me :)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue... Installing the EF from Package Manager Console worked for me

the command was: `Install-Package EntityFramework`

Answer (score 5):

If your compiler doesn't recognize

- System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
- DbContext
- DbSet
- et alii,

make sure

1. you have Entity Framework 4.1 installed on your machine;
2. in your .csproj file, you have the following reference

   ```
   <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
   ```

   within the element

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
     ...
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

   that houses references to other assemblies.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem..I have VS2010 express..

(Note: If you see this problem try checking references to EntityFramework.dll ..
May be it is missing.)

The following resolved it for me.

I installed latest [MVC 3 Tools Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1491)
then I installed [EntityFramework 4.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8363)
  or using 
NUGet ie. from with Visual Studio 2010 Express
(Tools->Library Package Manager -> Add library Package reference -> Select Online -> EntityFramework)

Strangely that didnt work..So i had to manually add a reference to "EntityFramework.dll"
try doing a  search for the dll ..may be here
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\"

If you already have it..just add a '.net' reference.

Note: If you use NuGet ,it creates a folder "packages" along side your Solution directory.
You will find the "EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0" folder inside it.Within "Libs" folder you will find
"EntityFramework.dll" .
 [Add reference to it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) using Browse tab and select the above dll.

[image: Snap for the same]

Answer (score 4):

I am using Visual Studio 2010 express and adding a reference to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1\Binaries\EntityFramework.dll` solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This helps really handy:

1. Select the ProjectNAme project in Solution Explorer.
2. From the Tools Menu, choose Library Package Manager which has a
   sub-menu.
3. From the sub-menu choose Package Manager Console.
4. At the console’s PM prompt type install-package EntityFramework then
   hit enter.

Answer (score 3):

For step-by-step instructions, see this new MVC / EF tutorial series:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application
The tutorial assumes you have installed the latest MVC 3 Tools Update and provides a link in case you haven't.

Answer (score 3):

Your project unable to resolve EntityFramework classes until you not added it in your project.
 For adding EntityFramework support you have to follow this steps:
Tools->Nuget Package Manager ->Manage Nuget package for solution
browse EntityFramework
It shows latest stable EntityFramework version.
currently 6.1.3 is latest version
Install it for the selected project.

Answer (score 3):

Download http://www.dll-found.com/download/e/EntityFramework.dll

Paste it in (for x86)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\
```

Then Right *click on project -> add reference -> select EntityFramework*

Bingo......

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Express SP1
Right click in Solution Explorer > References > Add Library Package Reference > EntityFramework

Answer (score 2):

Use [CTP5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18116) instead it is newer version with some changes in API. You have to add reference to EntityFramework.dll which is installed in CTP directory - default is: c:\Program Files\Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework Feature CTP5\Binaries\EntityFramework.dll for 32bit system. On 64bit system it will be placed in Program Files (x86).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, read the above answer and download the entityframework.ddl but found that it is alreadt referenced. So I added the namespace and problem was solved

using System.Data.Entity;

I am using Visual Studio 2010, SP1 installed

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I branched code. To fix it I right-clicked my project in Visual Studio, chose manage Nu-get packages, uninstalled EntityFramework, then re-installed it. Problem solved

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and none of the other solutions worked for me. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I have two projects in my solution: UIProject and DataAccessProject. The UIProject has a reference to the DataAccessProject.

My UIProject was targeting the .Net Framework 4 but my DataAccessProject was targeting the .Net Framework 3.5 for some reason.

- I changed both projects to target .Net Framework 4
- Uninstalled then re-installed the Entity Framework NuGet Package.

Problems solved. Now I have references to both EntityFramework and System.Data.Entity

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.I had to rewrite "DBContext" after adding reference to entityframework and it resolved the problem.
its means that Visual studio was not able to recognize the class automatically and waited for it to be re-typed. 
so its best to add reference first and then implement code. 
VS 2013 - ultimate used

Answer (score 2):

I had to first uninstall EntityFramework(Uninstall-package EntityFramework (not case sensitive apparently)), then install it again(Install-package EntityFramework), via the PM Console

Answer (score 1):

having referenced entityframework.dll both system.data.entity worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but the problem was just an accidental problem with my model.

I accidentaly put...

```
public class MyModelDBContext : Context
{
 public DBSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
}
```

...inside of the model class.

Comment: Those 3 line actually inside the class?

Answer (score 1):

Right click your reference and go to manage NuGet packages, then choose online all, then NuGet package source in the search textbox type Entity Framework and install it.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative way you can go [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906.aspx) - instruction how to install any required dll.

Or you can download [NuGet](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c) and manage it from VS

Answer (score 1):

1) Uninstalling Entity Framework from **All** projects

2) Restart Visual Studio

3) Reinstalling to all required projects

and **it started working**

Answer (score 1):

There might be a case where you reference everything you need to and you can even Go to Definition by pressing F12 on DbContext class which takes you to System.Data.Entity namespace but you still get this nasty compiler warning. Make sure that the Target Framework of your project and that of the Entity Framework version you are using match. Go to Project->Properties->Application Tab. Change the Target Framework(can't exactly say to which one, trial and error will help.). Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

I also get irritated from this issue many times and finally find the solution.Go to edmx file->Update Model from Database->Refresh->Finish.
Clean Solution->Rebuild Solution

Answer (score 0):

you can try on package manager console

PM> EntityFrameWork\enable-migrations

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have suggested:

1. Add the correct references and directives. But it still doesn't work? Maybe you have the same problem I did:

Have a look below and see if you can tell me what is wrong:

`public class PanelLengthContext : DBContext {     }` **??!**

## Make sure the class name is not misspelt - (case sensitivity)!

- `DbContext` is the correct spelling.
- this is how it should look:
- check the spelling. don't waste 20 min of your life like i did. `public class PanelLengthContext : DbContext {}`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you, I'm unable to implement it in the Controller class while it works when I put it in the model class. Add these codes on the top of your controller class

```
 using TimeSheetManagementSystem.Data;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
```