# DbContext error with asp.net , solved but not sure why or how

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building the MSV Music Store http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

I ran into a roadblock where there was an issue with the Entity Framework.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
  public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
  {
      public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
  }
}
```

There error I was getting was...

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'DBContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\ASP\MvcMusicStore\Models\MusicStoreEntities.cs   8   39  MvcMusicStore

I then found this question where there was a similar problem...

[The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741109/the-type-or-namespace-name-dbcontext-could-not-be-found)

EDIT: Using this question I had added the "system.data.entity" reference but was still experiencing the same error.

But then I saw another answer there that resolved the issue which said to change `DbContext` to `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

This has resolved my issue.

I'm wondering why, as I'm unsure of the purpose having to include `System.Data.Entity`, and why simply adding the reference didnt work.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5741167/2777098

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need to edit the question, as I tried that and I was still getting the error.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. It said you solved the problem; then still have problem. **Please edit your question.**

Comment: Ive edited it now, apologies the point i was making was that adding the reference didnt work, but literally typing `system.data.entity` did the job. I just dont know why

Comment: That's why I referenced this SO answer that explains why: stackoverflow.com/a/5741167/2777098

Comment: @Adrian IsabelHM's [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5741167/2777098) and the SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741109/the-type-or-namespace-name-dbcontext-could-not-be-found) in your question already answer your quesiton - **Im wondering why?**

Comment: Just to aid understanding a little more, these types of issues are unfortunately pretty common with .NET. Microsoft decided to make certain pieces of .NET nuget packages so they could be updated independently of the core. That's a good thing. However, most of these nuget packages merely extend existing namespaces in .NET. In particular here, `System.Data.Entity` exists in .NET without Entity Framework, but `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` comes from EntityFramework.dll, and doesn't exist unless that nuget is installed. Sometimes including the namespace isn't enough.