# How to know what assembly to add C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, using

I've ran into this issue a couple times and I'm wondering if anyone has a better solution than trial and error or searching stack overflow.

**Lets say we are using some .net class Foo**

**Foo resides in the Bar.Baz namespace**

The following statement

```
using Bar.Baz;
```

is not sufficient to compile the program, we are missing an assembly reference. So add a reference to `System.Bar.Baz` It still doesn't work so after searching the internet I find that I actually have to add a reference to `Some.Other.dll` and now it compiles.

My question is how do I know what namespace maps to what reference when the usual one doesn't work?

Most recent problem was
[The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741109/the-type-or-namespace-name-dbcontext-could-not-be-found) Instead of adding a reference to System.Data.Entity I had to install through Nuget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a .NET framework function, you can just search it on MSDN, and it will tell you in which assembly the class/function exists.

You can also use *ReSharper* which is a very nice plugin to Visual Studio, and it can help you add assemblies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2013 or higher, one easy way to discover which namespace a class belongs to is using the **Peek definition** feature. You can easily find it in the right-click context menu.

In the screen below, I used it with `KeyValuePair`:

[image: Peek definition screenshot]

Also, take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn160178.aspx).

Comment: This only works if the reference is already wired up correctly; i.e. you already have the correct assembly included.  OP is asking how to find the correct assembly when a type/namespace cannot be found because the correct reference is not there.