# Compiler errors: DbContext (and) DbSet not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Of course, the project references System.Data.Entity and the source is using System.Data.Entity. 
Also, I tried to install the latest version from the nuget console, as follow:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.3
```

Installing 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.
Desktop.Client already has a reference to 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'.

So is, I´m referencing the latest version.

What´s going? Could someone help?

TIA

Comment: check the answer on this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741109/the-type-or-namespace-name-dbcontext-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Did you install it in the correct project?

Answer (score 0):

[image] 
 1. Open our Project

2. Go To SolutionExplorer->refrences
3. Select EntityFarmework References Right click Remove references
4. References right click Manage NuGet Packages
5. select EntityFrmawork Clik To Install
6. added Latest Version EntityFramework

Comment: When I do exactly what you tell, the EntityFramework 6.x is marked as already installed (a green tilde). Nevertheless, if I browse assemblies, System.Data.Entity appears as version 4.0. Some more ideas? Thank you